# The data type cannot be changed because not enough spcae memory

Tags: ms-access, ms-access-2007, ms-access-2010

I imported a database into MS ACCESS, but the date field has dataytpe as text and written as APR2010, AUG2011, so on. I want to convert it into proper date (last day of the month and year) so that i can sort it and can plot it.
When iam directly changing the datatype in field its displaying the message that "the data type cannot be changed because not enough space memory).

Any solutions?

Answer (score 2):

Easy answer would be to do it in a stepped manner.

1. Create a new column for the date with the appropriate type
2. Run an update to set the contents of the new column with the appropriately formatted version of the original column
3. Ensure that the data is all-good
4. Drop the original column (or safer to rename it)
5. Rename the new column to that of the original
6. Get a coffee

Comment: I would place step 6 in between step 2 and 3 ;)

Comment: @luk2302 that really is dependant on the data set. It might be prudent to tackle step 6 first to allow for smoother operation of the other steps.

Comment: I agree with your answer, though it might be a good idea to expand as to what the cause of the issue is.  I realize for a tech person the answer might be obvious, but not all programmers are also tech people.

Answer (score 1):

In your update query you can use this expression to obtain the last day of any month:

```
SET [NewTrueDate] = DateAdd("d", -1, DateAdd("m", 1, DateValue(Format([OldTextDate], "1 @@@ @@@@"))))
```